# JDK 16 Records, Constructors and Additions Over Time?

Tags: java, java-16

I'm interested in using the new JDK 16 records, but when I try and create a new one that has additional arguments, I get an error:

```
public record DrivePacket(Path drivePath, long driveSize) {
        public DrivePacket(Path drivePath, long driveSize) {
            this.drivePath = drivePath;
            this.driveSize = driveSize;
        }
        public DrivePacket(Path drivePath, long driveSize, String ID) {
            this(drivePath, driveSize);
            this.id = id;
        }
}
```

Are records only for objects that have no variability whatsoever, or can they be extended over time?

I have a new requirement for this type of class (notably that the drive type "remote" drive over an NFS share has unexpectedly been added.

I find myself trying to come up with schemes like using the `driveSize` to indicate "remote" status, but really this is why enums were developed.

What should I do in this case? Can I add options to the constructor and store them in private final fields? Or should I make a subclass of `DrivePacket` -> `RemoteDrivePacket`, or should I make a marker interface for `RemoteDrivePacket`?

What is the typical way that the developers intended for this to be used?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/records.html You've defined the record as having two properties (`drivePath` and `driveSize`), you can't turn around and add an arbitrary property to it. Record classes cannot be subclassed; they are implicitly `final`. They can be extended, but you're attempting to do it at the wrong level.

Comment: @DaveNewton So for adding new functionality, either modify existing classes, or don't use a record to being with. Seems prone to failure from design oversight, or mission creep over the long term :)

Comment: Records were designed w/ a specific purpose. In your case if you defined the record as having an ID and had a ctor that called the canonical ctor w/ a dummy ID (or whatever) it would be fine as-is. You can also use static factories, although it doesn't seem necessary here. I don't really see a failure point or design oversight here; they are explicitly designed to be light-weight data carrier classes.

Comment: And if your application needs the broader features of classes ... such as subclassing so that that aspect of your design can evolve without recoding ... use regular classes.  Yes - you *do* need to make the right decisions early on to anticipate future requirements.  But that applies across the board.

Comment: Read [JEP 395](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) to learn all about records, the reason for their invention, and the features and limits.

Comment: I'd add also that even with a regular class this wouldn't be done the way shown in the example where an arbitrary member property (the un-conventionally named `ID`) is trying to be set--you'd add a member property normally, just like would be done with a record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They cannot be subclassed, and they can't have fields in the sense of 'adding one separately', but you can simply toss a new property in there; `public record DrivePacket(Path drivePath, long driveSize, String id) {}` works fine.

Of course, now all code that creates new DrivePacket objects needs to be updated. You should be able to add a custom constructor that e.g. fills in some default value.

If you want them to be buildable, expandable, have non-final fields, etc, have a look at [lombok's @Value](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value). (DISCLAIMER: I do work on lombok).

--EDIT--

I thought I'd add that constructor here, to show how you can ensure that 'old' code that invokes `new DrivePacket(path, size)` (no id) would work:

```
public record DrivePacket(Path drivePath, long driveSize, String id) {
    public DrivePacket(Path drivePath, long driveSize) {
        this(drivePath, driveSize, "");
    }
}
```

The 'full' all-3-of-em constructor *also* exists, this defines a second one, ensuring that any code that just goes `new DrivePacket(path, size)` gets an ID of `""`. All DrivePackets have an ID (you can't have half of em have it and the other half not; then 'DrivePacket' would no longer describe a single type concept, not how java works), and now old-style DrivePacket objects have an empty string for an ID.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to compatibly *add* a component to a record, if there is a reasonable default value, and this was considered during the design of this feature.  Consider:

```
record Point(int x, int y) { }
```

and you want to add a `z` component, where zero is a reasonable default.  If you just blindly changed it to

```
record Point(int x, int y, int z) { }
```

this would not be source- or binary- compatible with existing clients, but you can address this by providing an alternate constructor for the old state description:

```
record Point(int x, int y, int z) { 
    public Point(int x, int y) { this(x, y, 0); }
}
```

Now, old constructor invocations (binary and source) and old serialized instances (if the default value is the same zero default that serialization will use for fields not present in the serialized stream) will work as expected.  It is not, however, compatible to *rename*, *reorder*, or *remove* components.

Comment: Can you not safely remove a component by declaring another constructor with the now-removed parameter simply ignored? `public Point(int x, int y, int z) { this(x, y); }`

Comment: @MattLeidholm There may be also existing clients who call the accessor for the deleted component; you'd need to fake these guys out too with an explicit accessor that always returns a (valid under the old rules) default value.  But even with this, it is riskier.